# How to obtain a user instance using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, user-profile

Perhaps the question is wrongly worded. I created user profile using Django through the following blocks of code:

```
models.py

class = Profile (models.Models):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
•••

serializer.py
class profile_serializer(serializers.ModerlSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

views.py
class profile_view(generics.ListCreateAPIView)
    queryset = Profile.objects.all().filter(user=instance)

urls.py
urlspatterns = [path('profile', profile_view.as_view(), name='user_profile)
```

I definitely do not know how to implement the filter method to ensure that only the logged in user is retrieved. Or is there a better approach to obtain a specific user? If I use `Project.objects.all()` without the filter I get all the registered user as expected. But I don't know how to retrieve a particular user.

Comment: define a method `get_quersyset` and inside it use `self.request.user` as the user.

Comment: I have added `def get_queryset(self):` to models.py and  returned `self.request.user` but I keep getting all users returned`. The issue remains

Comment: you had to add this method to the `view` `class` where you wanted the current user. Also, you may not necessarily want to return `self.request.user` but the filtered `queryset` depending upon the logged-in user.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would do something like this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, generics, permissions


class UserView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = profile_serializer

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        return Response(profile_serializer(user).data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Basically when a user is authenticated, their user is present in the request.

Here's the UserSerializer, comments was hard to format. (Ironically for a tech forum?)

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def get(self, instance):
        return instance

    def patch(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.model_method()
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        return super().update(user, validated_data)
```

And here's the profile_serializer:

```
class profile_serializer(serializers.ModerlSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', )
```

Comment: Thanks so much@Joakim. Your approach looks better than the one I was trying to implement. But when I updated my views.py as stated in your answer, I got another error. `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'user' on serializer 'user_profile_serializer'. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not matched any attribute or key on the 'UserBase' instance. Original exception text was: 'UserBase' object has now attribute 'user'. ` I don't understand why the error is making reference to the user model because my user model class name is UserBase.